# Как выпускать обновления Unity Windows

Tags: unity3d

Я не совсем понимаю, как выпускать обновления для игры? Не загружать же целый билд весом с игру? Игра качается через мой лаунчер, с сервера. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)